# Line break mode and adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth not working obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am populating a view with multiple buttons (number of buttons is varying. Size of buttons and button titles is varying). I need to set button titles in 2 lines or 1 line according to number of words in the title. Also the font size should be compatible with the button frame size. Including some of my code here.
`

```
     // --------------------------
    button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNovaSoft-Bold" size:35];
button1.titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    button1.titleLabel.lineBreakMode= NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    button1.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    [button1.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];

   // --------------------------

    [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgColor1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button1];

    button2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button2.tag=2;
    [button2 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(createAlert:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/6-5, button1.frame.origin.y+(button1.frame.size.height/3)+button1.frame.size.height/2+15, self.view.bounds.size.width/3, self.view.bounds.size.width/3);
    NSString *imgColor2 = [alertColorArray objectAtIndex:1];
    if ([imgColor2 isEqualToString:@"RED"] || [imgColor2 isEqualToString:@"BLUE"] || [imgColor2 isEqualToString:@"YELLOW"]) {
        imgColor2 = [imgColor2 stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    }
    else
    {
        imgColor2 = @"YELLOW.png";
    }
    [button2 setTitle:[alertNameArray objectAtIndex:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    button2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNovaSoft-Bold" size:25];

     // --------------------------
   // button2.titleLabel.lineBreakMode= NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    button2.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;
    button2.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

     // --------------------------
    [button2.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgColor2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button2];
```

`

But this is not working as I need. What wrong with this?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by counting number of words in the text and `numberoflines` is set accordingly.`button1.titleLabel.numberOfLines=[self wordCount:[alertNameArray objectAtIndex:0]];`

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
//change scale factor accordingly

    [LABEL setMinimumScaleFactor:12.0/[UIFont labelFontSize]];
```